# Python code works, same Java code does not

Tags: java, python, graph-theory

I have a graph which is described as a map with the structure (it is the same both for Java and Python, but the example is in Python):

```
graph = {'A': ['B', 'C'],
     'B': ['A', 'C', 'D'],
     'C': ['A', 'B', 'D', 'F'],
     'D': ['B', 'C'],
     'E': ['F'],
     'F': ['C', 'E']}
```

I want to get all the paths from 'A'  to 'E'. For Python it works perfectly:

```
def find_all_paths(graph, start, end, path=[]):
path = path + [start]
if start == end:
    return [path]
paths = []
for node in graph[start]:
    if node not in path:
        newpaths = find_all_paths(graph, node, end, path)
        for newpath in newpaths:
            paths.append(newpath)
return paths

OUTPUT: [['A', 'B', 'C', 'F', 'E'], ['A', 'B', 'D', 'C', 'F', 'E'], ['A', 'C', 'F', 'E']]
```

But in Java I don't get the right result:

```
    static List<List<String>> findAllPaths(String start, String end, List<String> path) {
    path.add(start);
    if (start.equals(end)) {
        return List.of(path);
    }
    List<List<String>> paths = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String node : graph.get(start)) {
        if (!path.contains(node)){
            List<List<String>> newpaths = findAllPaths(node, end, path);
            paths.addAll(newpaths);
        }
    }
    return paths;
}

OUTPUT: [[A, B, C, D, F, E]]
```

I have debugged it and got to know that Python stores `path` variable for each function call, while Java stores this variable as a global variable for all the functions. However, I am not sure. Do you have any suggestions what the reasons are for that?

Comment: How are you calling this method?

Comment: `path = path + [start]` is not equivalent to `path.add(start)`. The Python version is making a new list; the Java version is altering the old list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`path = path + [start]` is not equivalent to `path.add(start)`. The Python version is making a new list; the Java version is altering the existing list.

The Java equivalent of `path = path + [start]` would be to copy the list first, then add the new element.

```
path = new ArrayList<>(path);
path.add(start);
```